# Why do 3-phase selective circuit breakers appear as separate (not joined) ones?

Tags: circuit-breaker, automatic-circuit-breaker

I'm looking at 3-phase selective circuit breakers like this:

[image: ABB S751 selective circuit breaker]

Unlike a typical 3-phase circuit breaker, this selective breaker appears to be essentially 3 separate breakers all put together. Strangely enough, they are sold together but also sold separately with labels L1, L2 and L3. I'm trying to understand *why* it is done this way. Specifically, assuming there is a downstream 3/4-pole circuit breaker that can be triggered, what's the advantage of having separate poles that are not joined? Why would these be sold under separate labels (L1, L2, L3) -- they appear to be identical boxes, do they maybe interconnect in the middle somehow?

Update: this is the ABB S751-3 breaker.

Comment: Add the datasheet link for the product into your question, please (and not in the comments).

Comment: Maybe sometimes you do not want everything shutting down when one phase goes. Like in a manufacturing plant that can limp along with two phases to the motor resulting in decreased, but continued production.

Comment: Cost as well.  The plant already makes a single-pole breaker.  Want a 2-pole or 3?  No problem, just slap them together.  In the US, all that's required is a method to connect the handles, so if one trips, the others will as well.  However, I am still interested in your question for the circumstances in which they would not be tied together (and is it allowed by the regulations?)...

Comment: @Chris In some applications you need **common trip** (one overloads: all trip).  That's accomplished with an internal mechanism. The handle-ties are not capable of that because handles "trip free" - the breaker will trip even if locked in the "on" position. The handle ties only protect maintainers (make sure they shut off the whole circuit).  On some Euro breakers, there's a hole or slot in the side of the breakers and as you stack them, you can insert an actuating rod to get common trip. US breakers don't allow this, so all common-trip breakers are riveted together from the factory.

Comment: @DKNguyen Running a motor that way would be bad, but a heater wouldn't care. Also European 3-phase works very well with *multi-wire branch circuits* 3 hots sharing 1 neutral - 5 wires instead of 7.  On a MWBC with all single-phase loads, you don't need common trip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they are designed to sit on a horizontal 3-phase bus bar. In this configuration the supply is provided by three horizontal bus bars running from left to right. This arrangement means that you can not manufacture a single single phase breaker that would be mountable on any of the phases, it would need to physically draw power from a different location and so need a different model for each phase. And so this package. The left breaker is drawing from the top bus bar, the middle breaker from the middle bar, and the right from the bottom bar. Since you usually want to split the loads somewhat evenly, it is probably easier to buy 5 of these selective breakers, than 5 L1 breakers, 5 L2 breakers, and 5 L3 breakers.

This could be avoided by using a more complex bus bar arrangement to always present the phase drawn at the same height, but that would be significantly more complex. (Because you have 3 phases, you would need multiple levels, not just an interlaced fingers design common in us residential breaker buses). Additionally, this approach does allow you to vary the number of breakers on the different phases, if for example you want two smaller breakers on one phase, and a larger breaker on another phase.